# Thymeleaf - Form for each object in list

Tags: java, binding, thymeleaf

I'm new to Thymeleaf and try to solve the following problem:

```
class Person() {
   int id;
   String name;

   // getter & setter;
}
```

Snippet from the Controller-class:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"..."})
public ModelAndView getXXX(HttpServletRequest request)
{
   ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("xxx");
   ...
   List<Person> persons = ... // Let's say a list of Persons {1: "Peter", 2: Anna}
   mv.addObject("persons", persons);
   ...
   return mv;
}
```

Now, in template xxx.html I try to create a form for each person in persons (not 1 form for all persons in persons). My approach so far:

```
<form th:each="p, stat : ${persons}" 
      th:object="${persons[stat.index]}" 
      th:action="..." method="POST" >

    <input th:field="*{name}" type="text">
</form>
```

No surprise: this doesn't work. If I remove the input-element, no Exception occures. With the input-element I get the following message (Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException):

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'persons[stat' available as request attribute
```

Is there a way to only add a list of objects to the model and still be able to create forms for each object of the list and bind the coresponding object to each form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller seems to be somewhat wrong.

See here https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html

so

```
@RequestMapping(value = "message", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String messages(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("messages", messageRepository.findAll());
        return "message/list";
    }
```

You simply pass objects(or list) you want into model object

```
model.addAttribute("attributeename", attributeobject)
```

then you should be able to iterate it.

EDIT: i dont know how to english...

Comment: Thanks, but that is something completly different and not even a problem (there are plenty of options for the controller design, the model can be an input parameter, you can only return the view's name, you can return a ModelAndView object [I prefer it that way] ... you can use the RequestMapping-Annotation, you can use the Get/Post/../../-Mapping [introduced with Spring 4.3]).